# TSQL Union, Max(date) - have solution. Want improvement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, union, max

The following query works, but there has to be a better way to set the value of a table to the max date of the union of two sets of data.  Here's what I have:

```
Update stagingTable
Set OverrideFlag = 
(
select total.overrideflag from
    (
    select Customer_SSN as ssn, RequestDateTime as maxdate, overrideflag
    from tableA
    where RequestDateTime > '9/1/2012'
    union
    select ssn, EntryDate as maxdate, overrideflag
    from tableB
    where EntryDate > '9/1/2012'
    )  total
    join
    (
    select ssn, max(maxdate) as maxdate from
        (
        select Customer_SSN as ssn, RequestDateTime as maxdate
        from tableA
        where RequestDateTime > '9/1/2012'
        union
        select ssn, EntryDate as maxdate
        from tableB
        where EntryDate > '9/1/2012'
        ) maxs
        group by ssn
    ) maxdates  on total.ssn = maxdates.ssn and total.maxdate = maxdates.maxdate        where total.ssn = stagingTable.ssn
)
```

Comment: Could you please provide examples of input and output (what you are trying to receive) data/tables?

Comment: Sure.  There are two tables, TableA and TableB.  TableA has a customerID varchar(15), SSN varchar(11), date datetime, and overrideflag varchar(2).  So does TableB.  The staging table has a varchar(2) for the overrideflag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you are doing the exact same thing twice, so I am not getting the need to define something twice and join it back to itself unless there was something different in one of the nested selects.  You are essentially writing the same statement twice and the redundancy may be an issue as one of the selects appears completely redundant.

```
-- this is a CTE and is better for reuse than a nested select as you can reference it
-- is as a base and reuse that, versus having to write the same statement twice.
;with a as 
    (
     select 
         Customer_SSN as ssn, 
         RequestDateTime as maxdate, 
         OverRideFlag,
         -- EDIT, you should be able to use a 'Windowed function' to get the maxDate
         max(RequestDateTime) over(partition by SSN order by RequestDateTime desc) as maxDate
     from tableA
     where RequestDateTime > '9/1/2012'
     union
     select 
          ssn, 
          EntryDate, 
          OverRideFlag, 
          max(RequestDateTime) over(partition by SSN order by RequestDateTime desc) as maxDate
     from tableB
     where EntryDate > '9/1/2012'
    )
Update stagingTable
Set OverrideFlag = total.overrideflag
from a total
   join stagingTable on total.ssn = stagingTable.ssn  
   -- do not know reference here so you need to add that table as a 'join' 
where total.EntryDate = total.maxDate
```

Comment: I needed the value of overrideflag from the latest date, so that's why I needed the max(maxdate):
select ssn, max(maxdate) as maxdate

Comment: My apologies I missed that portion of nesting a nested select to get that.  You should be able to use a 'Windowed function' to get that part.  See my updated example.

Answer (score 0):

I also found a different way to do it with a temp table.  I'm becoming very comfortable with these, but I always want to see a different way how to do this.  Not disappointed!

```
create table #tOvr(customerID varchar(15), ssn varchar(11), EntryDate datetime, overrideflag varchar(2))
insert into #tOvr
select customer_ID, Customer_SSN, RequestDateTime, overrideflag
from tableA
where RequestDateTime > '9/1/2012'
and Customer_ID in 
    (select contact_ID from stagingTable
    where Location_ID = @Location_ID)
insert into #tOvr
select Customer_ID, ssn, EntryDate, overrideflag
from tableB
where EntryDate > '9/1/2012'
and Customer_ID in 
    (select contact_ID from stagingTable
    where Location_ID = @Location_ID)

Update stagingTable
Set OverrideFlag =
    (select overrideflag from #tOvr
    where EntryDate = (select max(EntryDate) from #tOvr where #tOvr.customerID = stagingTable.contact_ID)
    )
```

Comment: A cool thing about temp tables is you do not have to define them first to insert into them.  The lazy man, me, a lot of times does this instead:  Select * into #Temp from (object).  Then if I have to ensure it does not first exist I do this IF object_id('tempdb..#Temp') is not null drop table #Temp.  It's not the best thing to be lazy at all times but it saves you quite a bit of code if you are not picky of declaring your types and they will just be assumed this way.